# Laravel/Lumen sçubida de archivos múltiple

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php5, lumen

Tengo esta función que su proposito es que reciba diversos ficheros por post y los guarde en su respectiva carpeta , para ello tengo un array de archivos que se llama file[] y envio todos los archivos de golpe , hago un bucle y los intento tratar uno a uno.

```
    /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function uploadSubmit(Request $request)
{
    $input=$request->all();

    if($files=$request->file('file')){
        foreach($files as $file){
            try {

            $file = $request->file;
            $file->store('public');

            $attributes['file']  = Storage::disk('public')->url($file->hashName());
            $attributes['user_id'] = 1;

            $fileLibrary = FileLibrary::create($attributes);

            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json([
                    'errors' => $e->getMessage()
                ], 500);
            }

        }
    }
```

El error que me da es en esta linia

```
                $file->store('public');
```

Call to a member function store() on array

Answer (score 0):

Porque esta linea `$file = $request->file;` si `$file` ya te lo traes del foreach?

Además cambiaría

```
if($files=$request->file('file')){
```

por lo siguiente, si lo que quieres es comprobar que en `$files`viene algo

```
$files=$request->file('file')    
if($files){
```